# Using jquery to select an item from a select list based on the label

Tags: javascript, jquery

So if I have a select list of lets say dates that looks like

```
<option value="624e70cb-2796-4029-bd09-2642abaa54b4">1989</option>
<option value="ff591d9a-e8a4-4280-829b-9307b7b41912">1988</option>
<option value="f2e9e756-7c59-4883-89b5-9c8cccf85ad6">1987</option>
<option value="c65d6a65-441f-4cb5-9e6d-d9de58efb060">1986</option>
<option value="27aa2cd0-f77a-48c0-83f3-5348d5a7239f">1985</option>
<option value="50e375c0-a1fa-405e-8ec9-a3f220041a39">1984</option>
```

if I have a string that holds the value 86 is there a good way to select:

```
<option value="c65d6a65-441f-4cb5-9e6d-d9de58efb060">1986</option>
```

with jquery?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('#yourselectid').val("1986");
```

Comment: Thanks for the speedy response guys :)
Also one more question if it is not to much, Does .val take wildcard characters

Comment: Not that I know of,  but if its a multi select box you can select multiple options using an array: `$("#multiple").val(["Multiple2", "Multiple3"]);`, see the examples [here](http://api.jquery.com/val/)

Comment: Dam my friend that solves my problem perfectly it is as thou you red my brain. Thank you jon.

Comment: Jquery is an amazing library with tons of functionality.  If you ever think "why doesn't Javascript do that?" check Jquery.  Glad I could help.

Answer (score 1):

http://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/

```
var matchedSelectors = $("option:contains('" + string + ')");
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<script>
var myvar = 86;
$('option[text='+ ( '19' + myvar ) +  ']')
</script>
```

This should do it